# Cómo obtener el día anterior en una expresión de SSIS

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, ssis

Estoy intentando obtener la fecha para un "Script Task" con una expresión pero quiero que el día este restado por uno, es decir, si obtengo la fecha 2022-07-05, me la devuelva como 2022-07-04

Hasta el momento esto es lo que tengo

```
(DT_WSTR,4)YEAR(GETDATE()) + RIGHT("0"+(DT_WSTR,2)MONTH(GETDATE()),2 + RIGHT("0"+(DT_WSTR,2)DAY(GETDATE()),2)
```

¿Alguna solución?

Comment: Uso eso para devolver la última fecha del mes pasado.  Tal vez le ayuda  dateadd("day",
-1,
(DT_DATE)((DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART( "yyyy" ,dateadd("month", -1, getdate())) + "-" + (DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART( "mm" ,dateadd("month", -1, getdate())) + "-1"))

Answer (score 0):

Buen dia,

Podrias solucionarlo con la funcion Dateadd, agregando -1 dia:

DATEADD(day,-1,GETDATE())

Pudiendo reempalazar GETDATE() por la fecha que necesites.

Saludos